# Diagonal with Drawline in VB2012

Tags: vb.net, gdi

I use this simple code to draw a diagonal line - but the line ends about in the middle of my form...
why ???

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click
        g.DrawLine(stift, 0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
     End Sub
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint and check your Width/Height variables at the time of clicking the button. Your code here should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with g in your example.  The Graphics Object seems to be limited to the drawing within the dimensions it's given when CreateGraphics() is called.  You can confirm this by following @Keith's suggestion to set a breakpoint and check g.VisibleClipBounds.Height and .Width (compared to Me.Height and Me.Width)

You'll see that Me.Height and Me.Width are changing, but the VisibleClipBounds properties are not.  My attempts to correct using the various *Clip* properties and methods of the Graphics object haven't worked so far, other than to dispose of g and recreate with another call to CreateGraphics().  So using your sample:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   Button1.Click
        g.Dispose()
        g = Me.CreateGraphics()
        g.DrawLine(stift, 0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
End Sub
```

HTH, 
Eric